# About Vakil's definition of (affine) scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In his notes, Ravi Vakil says that:

> An affine scheme is a ringed space that is isomorphic to $(\operatorname{Spec}A,\mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A})$ for some $A$.

However, it seems to me that the usual definition is slightly different:

> An affine scheme is a **locally** ringed space that is isomorphic to $(\operatorname{Spec}A,\mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A})$ for some $A$.

Lets assume Vakil's definition. I know that $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is a locally ringed space and so it follows that any affine scheme is a locally ringed space. What is not obvious to me is **why the isomorphism is an isomorphism of locally ringed spaces**. In other words, if $(f,f^{\#})$ is the isomorphism between our affine scheme and $\operatorname{Spec} A$, why is $f^{\#}$ local?

Comment: $f^{\#}$ is an isomorphism at each stalk, so carries the unique maximal ideal to the unique maximal ideal.